# Hide specific calendars in widget

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios

I'm running ios 11.1.1

I have multiple calendars linked to my phone (personal, work, wife, tv-shows,etc).

In the Calendar app, I was able to turn off my calendar which display air times of my favorite tv shows.  However, in the Calendar widget (when you swipe right from the home screen), it still shows the tv calendar.

These events are showing in both the "Up Next" calendar widget, as well as the normal calendar widget.  How can I select which calendars I want to see in the widget?  Turning them off in the Calendar app is not working, and I do not want to completely remove the calendar from my phone.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out what I was doing wrong.  Since I use the Outlook app for my mail, I also went into the calendar section of that to turn off the calendar I wanted to hide. So hiding it in the Outlook Calendar of course didn't work.

I went into the *Apple* calendar app and unselected the tv show calendar, and now it no longer shows up in the widget.

This was just a matter of hiding the calendar in the wrong app.